# Export array content during debug using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm currently porting some huge arithmetics from MATLAB to C++ including vast amount of data. I would like to step over C++ code in VS and compare contents of the key arrays with ones from MATLAB code being debugged simultaneously. Since there are many steps, it's very ugly to use some real C++ code for exporting values.

So, is there some convenient way to export content of known memory buffer from C++ to whatever? The only thing I can think of is to copy content of watch window. Some better ideas?

**Update:** Found `>d` command in Command Window. Almost fit my needs except 1) disturbing metainfo typed alongside with output, 2) only 10000 lines of output is possible :-|

Comment: I'm confused... you want to export data from a running C++ program without using C++ code? What is wrong with just writing your data to a file?

Comment: As I wrote, there are lots of simple statements, varying the same data. I don't know which statements are wrong, so I should save data after every statement. It is possible, yes, but I'm looking for more pleasing solution.

Comment: So what you are looking for is an interactive data dump of debugging info? I don't know how to do that... good luck though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, I was able to use `>d` command along with slight "packing" of my data to fit more in one string and performed several dumps. Since it was the one-moment task, solution is appropriate.